# Read & Display CSV File

Tags: angularjs

**Details:**
Trying to read totals.csv file from directory csvFiles and display a single number (which is all the csv file has in it). Not that it matters but the data is a single value for RMA totals created by MSSQL. For instance if the number in the file is 2866 I'd like to display that number on the screen.

**What I've Attempted**
I've tried to use the example below with out results. I replace the .htm file with totals.csv.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    Papa.parse("totals.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function (results) {
    $scope.results = results.data;
    $scope.fields = results.meta.fields;
    $scope.$apply();
    }
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    
    <div id="box1" class="displayBox" ng-app="" >
    <h1>2016 RMA TOTAL</h1>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='r in results'>
    <td ng-repeat='c in fields'>
    <h3>{{r[c]}}</h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    <div id="box2" class="displayBox">
    <h1>2017 RMA TOTAL</h1>
    <h3>846</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div id="box3" class="displayBox">
    <h1>2017 CLOSED RMAs </h1>
    <h3>565</h3>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <div class="clockContainer">
    <div id="date"></div>
    <ul>
    <li id="hours"></li>
    <li id="point">:</li>
    <li id="min"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to use csv parsing library on top of getting content of csv , eg http://papaparse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some library for csv parsing, eg [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/):

Inside your controller you are downloading file, parsing it and setting scope properties to data and header row (might be different with another library):

```
Papa.parse("//mysite/totals.csv", {
  download: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    $scope.results = results.data;
    $scope.fields = results.meta.fields;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
});
```

in your view you just iterate:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat='c in fields'>{{ c }}</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat='r in results'>
    <td ng-repeat='c in fields'>
      {{ r[c] }} 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Once I get to my other job I will look through this and evaluate. I will mark as answered in a bit. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, I modified the original code. I cannot get this to work and they are giving me until 6 to get this working....

Comment: there is not data being displayed. However, I am not sure if this will even work as all the examples I've seen with Papa Parse use a file input box to upload a file. Also this file basically has just a single line of text in it. So maybe it's best to just use a text file vs a CSV.

Comment: read through examples of papaparse, you you provide URL and set `download=true` option it will download file. i.e. will do get request to get file content.